# Android 2 finger touch triggering 1 finger touch as well as 2 finger touch

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, touch-event

I have an issue in my app where I need to perform a different action based on if one fingers or two fingers are pressed down.

Currently I have the follow code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        int touchX = (int)event.getX();
        int touchY = (int)event.getY();
        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        //Multitouch
        if(event.getPointerCount() > 1 && action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
            System.out.println("2 Finger press");

            return true;
        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){

            if(event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
                System.out.println("single finger down");
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The issue I am having is when I press with 2 fingers, the multitouch part registers, and after that so does the single press.

I did some googling around on ways to fix that and that would be why I am checking on the single touch conditional that `action != MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` which I thought would fix the issue. That didn't fix the issue hence I decided to check that `event.getPointerCount() == 1`, but unfortunately that still causes both lines to print when I press with 2 fingers.

To summarize I need to only call the 2 finger part when 2 fingers are pressed down and not both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

refer to the documentation on "[Handling Multi-Touch Gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html)". it details exactly what you're looking for.

in essence, each active pointer is assigned an ID when it makes contact with the screen. your solution will should take into account which IDs come into play and are removed by observing various action states.

something a little bit along these lines (but beware compatibility calls for methods like `getActionIndex()`):

***UPDATED CODE SAMPLE***

```
public class MotionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int primaryPointerId   = -1;
    private int secondaryPointerId = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new FrameLayout(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                primaryPointerId = event.getPointerId(0);

                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Primary pointer ID == [" + primaryPointerId + "]");

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                secondaryPointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());

                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Secondary pointer ID == [" + secondaryPointerId + "]");

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(primaryPointerId > -1 && secondaryPointerId > -1) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Two-point touch...");
                } else {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "One-point touch...");
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                if(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == primaryPointerId) {
                    primaryPointerId = secondaryPointerId;
                }

                secondaryPointerId = -1;

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                primaryPointerId = -1;

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to reread the documentation on that and work out how to do it. I believe your sample code is wrong, however, it doesn't register 2 finger presses at all. I think this is caused by secondaryPointerId = -1 which means the multi touch conditional is never met

Comment: `secondaryPointerId` should be assigned when an action of `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` is received. my mechanics on how to reference the correct action index may be off (i wrote that off memory), but the gist is correct. if `secondaryPointerId` == -1 it's because there's one (or no) fingers on the surface.

Comment: I was looking into it more and the issue is the `case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` is never actually entered and I'm yet to figure out why but other than that I think this is correct. I see what you mean about the secondaryPointerId

Comment: the problem with my code sample was i stupidly wrote it up with the pointer IDs as method-scoped variables. rather they should be member variables. i've pasted an updated, working version instead. sorry about that!

Comment: Awesome it is working as intended now. Thanks a million for the help!

Comment: glad to help! be sure to read the docs, though. it explains important framework behavior with respect to how pointer IDs are managed, for example in the case when the first pointer to touch is also the first one released, etc.